# Django Jsonresponse filtered queryset by id

Tags: json, django, django-queryset

My objective is to get the id and make a queryset filtered by id, as in the following code:

**views.py**

```
class MyProfile(TemplateView):
model = Reports
template_name = 'template.html'
def get_context_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('pk', None):
        q = kwargs.get('pk', None)
        queryset = Reports.objects.all().values('id','line_x','line_y',).filter(id = q)
        data = list(queryset)
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^profiles/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.MyProfile.as_view())
```

It returns the following error:

*context must be a dict rather than JsonResponse*

**Django 1.11.8**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def different_function_name(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('pk', None):
       q = kwargs.get('pk', None)
       queryset = Reports.objects.all().values('id','line_x','line_y',).filter(id = q) 
       query_list = list(queryset)
       return JsonResponse(query_list, safe=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, I know this solution, but I need to read data Json encoded, they will be used for a chart. If I create the querystring without the get_context_data, that is with .filter(id='199') it returns corretly by JsonResponse

Comment: Hi @Mixo I edited the answer in response to your comment.